# Git bash home directory different from Git extension than Git Bash

Tags: git, git-extensions

If i run Git bash from Git Extention (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), my home directory is %USERPROFILE%, which is ok.

If I run Git bash from the context menu of a git repo folder, or if I run Git bash from the start menu, my home directory is %HOME%, which is different.

How can I set up git bash to always use %USERPROFILE% as home directory (I have the .ssh folder within) ?

If it can help, on git bash run from Git Ext, I have :

```
$ echo $HOME
/c/Users/mylogin
```

Same command on git bash run directly :

```
$ echo $HOME
/h
```

`h:` is my corporate home directory

What can I do ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The git bash provided with [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) in [its repo](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) is a script you can edit, in order to set `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%`.
It is basically what it does by default, except if `HOME` is already defined, the git bash script won't modify that value (but you can, if you edit said script).

I suspect that, in your corporate environment, `HOME` is defined to a network drive, in order for various configuration files (maven, ssh, ...) to be stored on a remote, secure and backed-up drive.
That would explain why `HOME` is *not* changed by the Git bash script.
The Git Extension obviously isn't as careful as the first script, and will change/define whatever value it needs.

---

As the [OP Steve B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588868/steve-b) comments:

The `HOME` is set, for the Git bash, in [`etc/profile`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/etc/profile):

```
# Set up USER's home directory
if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
  HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
  if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    HOME="$USERPROFILE"
  fi
fi
```

> I removed the first candidate home location, and it works.

Comment: where is the script you are talking about ? And yes, H is a network drive, as I said in my question. However, as I'm working on a laptop, I don't want to use the network drive, but the local profile

Comment: oh I found it : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile`. There is the following code : `# Set up USER's home directory
if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
  HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
  if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    HOME="$USERPROFILE"
  fi
fi`. I removed the first candidate home location, and it works. thanks

Comment: @SteveB: good catch. I have edited the answer to make that `etc/profile` more visible.

Comment: I'm still thinking this is a mess. Why there is not a simple unique config file in the user's profile directory ?

Comment: @SteveB: But... that "simple unique config file" would be in the `HOME` directory of the user. And the `HOME` directory is precisely what you want to define! On Windows, there is no '`HOME`' by default, hence the system profile in `/etc`.

Comment: yeah... maybe this more a window design issue, having settings spread across registry, appdata dir, home dir, etc.

Comment: Note: These instructions do not affect the directory that Git Bash opens into.  To change that directory, I right clicked on the short-cut, and changed the 'Start in' field from $HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH to %USERPROFILE% .

Comment: @Patrick You should make your comment into an answer so I can vote it up.