# i cannot push to my new remote server GIT in windows 7

Tags: git, ssh

I created one Git server on Win7 with SSHD held by WinSSH,

i built remote git there with syntax

```
ssh user@128.21.33.5
cd GitRepo/GitCRM/
git --bare init
exit
```

i can do scp with syntax

```
scp myFile user@128.21.33.5:GitRepo/GitCRM/
```

but i always got failed when do this:

```
git push user@128.21.33.5:GitRepo/GitCRM/ master
```

error message is :

```
fatal : ''GitRepo/GitCRM/'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal : the remote end hung up enexpectedly
```

what should i fix?

== UPDATE ==
i install cygwin within openSSH to work as my new SSH server
and all work fine

Answer (score 1):

Even if ssh connects to your HOME, git might still need the full path:

```
git push user@128.21.33.5/home/YourLogin/GitRepo/GitCRM/ master
```

(and you are right to use `GitCRM` here, not `GitCRM.git`: since you have created a bare repo within `GitCRM/`, that directory is its own '`.git`')

---

Regarding SSH server, the [OP kreamik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099057/kreamik) went with an OpenSSH with Cygwin, easier to setup than a WinSSH.

Comment: i install winSSH in my windows and i don't know what is my home ..
any clue?
i test with C:/ or C:\ to my folder and it always give me error like i mention before ..
it seems that the path has generate it's own quote and it become double quote that makes it failed

Comment: You don't need WinSSH, and `HOME` isn't defined by default on Windows. Define it wherever you have stored your ssh keys. See here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454774/fix-msysgit-portable-home-location/3455231#3455231) how msysgit defines `HOME` for instance. As illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562715/6309, you can set `HOME` to any directory you want.