# Cannot connect to remote repository using SSH: connection timed out

Tags: git, ssh, git-extensions

I am trying out Git, using Git-Extensions on Windows, and have created local repositories without any problems.  I want to be able to work on my projects on various machines, so I am trying to make them accessible via my web host's machine.
Following the instructions in the Pro Git book, I've created a bare repository, and uploaded that to my on-line filespace. I've got SSH access working, adding the public key to .ssh/authorized_keys, and can log in OK using PuTTY. So far, so good.

However, I'm stuck trying to get an SSH connection working to the repository via GitExtensions. In the Manage Remote Repositories window, I've entered an ssh: URL, because my web host uses 15554 instead of the default SSH port number.  The URL I've added looks like:

```
ssh://myusername@mydomainname.co.uk:15554/git/myproject.git
```

The private key file is the same one I use successfully to connect using PuTTY.
When I hit the "Test Connection" button, a command prompt window appears and after about 10 seconds shows the message: "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out".

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong in the configuration, given that I can connect OK using the same SSH key with PuTTY.
Can anyone suggest what I'm missing?

Comment: So to make a regular ssh connection you would enter `myusername@mydomainname.co.uk:15554`?

Comment: Is it an HOME issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562715/6309?

Comment: Thanks - sorry for the late response - I didn't get any email notifications, which I thought I'd enabled.  I gave up and used bitbucket.org instead, which was much easier and very nice to use.