# Git prompting for password when using SSH, even when SSH keys are present (but running as admin works). What is the issue?

Tags: windows, git, ssh

In a corporate environment running Windows I have the following issue:

Using git via SSH via

```
git clone git@server:repo.git
```

I am prompted for a password:

```
git clone git@server:repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
git@server's password:
```

The SSH Key is not found, although my SSH key resides in `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.ssh`.

However, running the command shell (CMD) as administrator, everything works just fine.

**What is the issue and how can it be fixed?**

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I am answering my own question since the issue wasted hours of my time and I did not see it in other issues having similar "access denied" symptoms).

Getting "access denied" or haven SSH keys not recognised may have a variety of reasons, see also

- https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

The issue above - where git works when run as local admin, but not as user - is possibly related to a specific setup in a corporate environment. In my case the machine had a folder `C:\Users\[USERNAME]` but also a profile on a network mounted drive (say N). The .ssh folder with my key resided in `C:\Users\[USERNAME]` but git was looking in `N:`

Running as (Local) Administrator on the Machine changed the behaviour and used the profile from `C:\Users\[USERNAME]`.

To find your home folder:

- open Git Bash on Windows
- type `cd ~;pwd`

The issue is ultimately related to different settings of the environment variables HOMEDRIVE, HOMESHARE or USERPROFILE, see also [Git bash home directory different from Git extension than Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560064/git-bash-home-directory-different-from-git-extension-than-git-bash)

Comment: Fantastic ... exactly the same problem. Corporate environment! My solution was to move my C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.SSH files to the network mounted drive.  This might have the added benefit of whatever machine I go on the network with might have access to my SSH key